# Help getting the transfer function of a circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, transfer-function, single-supply-op-amp

I have been trying to get the transfer function of the circuit below for some days now and I eventually get to an expression but I don't believe I am geting the correct expression and here's why (the words "Circuito" translate directly to "circuit"):

Ignore the dotted lines, those are meant to guide the analysis. I have tried to get an expression by using the superposition of the two circuits that the dotted lines enclose. So I would have:

$$
V_{outA}=\bigg(1+\frac{R_{5}}{R_{4}}\bigg)V_{in}
$$
Since its just a mere non inverting configuration of the OpAmp. For the circuit B I would have:
$$
V_{outB}=\bigg(1+\frac{R_{5}}{R_{4}}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{R_{2}}{R_{2}+R_{3}}V_{+5}\bigg)
$$

and the total response at the opamp would then be:
$$
V_{out}=V_{outA}+V_{outB}=\bigg(V_{in}+\frac{R_{2}}{R_{2}+R_{3}}V_{+5}\bigg)\bigg(1+\frac{R_{5}}{R_{4}}\bigg)
$$

Finnaly at the passage through the RC filter it would be:

$$
V_{out}=\bigg(V_{in}+\frac{R_{2}}{R_{2}+R_{3}}V_{+5}\bigg)\bigg(1+\frac{R_{5}}{R_{4}}\bigg)\frac{1}{1+j\omega R_{6}C_{3}}
$$

when left in complex form. To get something to work with I wrote:

$$
|V_{out}|=\bigg|\bigg(V_{in}+\frac{R_{2}}{R_{2}+R_{3}}V_{+5}\bigg)\bigg(1+\frac{R_{5}}{R_{4}}\bigg)\bigg|\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(2\pi fR_{6}C_{3})^{2}}}
$$

$$
\phi=-\arctan(2\pi fR_{6}C_{3})
$$

However, when I use this expressions, and I fix the values of R1,R2,R4 o 1kOhm, R6 to 12kOhm, C1=1uF, C2=100uF and C3=150nF The values I get for a resistance in the places of the potentiometer are R3=5100Ohm and R5=2500Ohm when Vin is a 0.8V sinusoidal signal and Vout will be a 2.5V sinusoidal signal with a 2.5V offset. But in practice I had to use a 20k potentiometer in R5 and a 10k for R3 so My intuition is that my expression is wrong, and the simulations in multisim also point in that direction. Where is my mistake?

PS: This circuit as appeared in two other questions here in the stack  but I am a bit desperate to get a correct answer and its killing me not knowing where my mistake is.
[image]

Comment: What is V1, in your circuit?

Comment: Its nothing. It was just something to help explainging the analysis. Just a label. I forgot to get it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the fact that \$R_3\$ is a potentiometer. It is much more complicated than you think. And to simplify the equations, you should pick \$R_3 << R_2\$. Or add a voltage follower between POT wiper and \$R_2\$

Then we can write the equation for the voltage at the non-inverting input:

$$V_{NI} = V_1\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}+ V_{IN}\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} $$

Or if we include the POT in the equation:

$$V_{NI} = \alpha V_{+5}\frac{R_1}{R_1+(1 -\alpha)\alpha R_3+R_2}+ V_{IN}\frac{(1 -\alpha)\alpha R_3+R_2}{R_1+(1 -\alpha)\alpha R_3+R_2} $$

Where: 
\$\alpha =\$ POT wiper position from 0 to 1.

And since \$R_3\$ POT is supplied from a DC voltage it will create a DC offset at the op-amp output.

Equal to $$V_{offset} =  \alpha V_{+5}\frac{R_1}{R_1+(1 -\alpha)\alpha R_3+R_2} \left( 1 + \frac{\alpha_5 R_5}{R_4}\right)$$

Where 
\$\alpha_5 =\$  is a \$R_5\$ POT wiper position from 0 to 1.

All this means that if for example, the DC offset at the op-amp output is set by \$R_3\$ to \$2.5V\$.

Then the op-amp output voltage will be:

$$V_O = 2.5V + V_{IN} \left( 1 + \frac{\alpha_5 R_5}{R_4}\right) $$

So, now you got all the information needed to solve your problem.

Comment: That is much more complicated than I thought, and definitely helps. Just got confused on something, you considered V1 to be just a label and not an external source, right? And what is the V_NI?

Comment: @Bidon V1 is just a label included on your schematic (output voltage from R3 pot). And V_NI  = Voltage at Non-Inverting input.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks, I'll re-do my analysis. Thank you

Comment: but all the work that you made is considering R3<<R2, right? In my case I don't know if that's true, because R2 is fixed at 1kOhm. Does it alter much the equations?

Comment: Also, to get the notation right. When you write R3 or R5 that is to be interpreted as the maximum resistance of the potentiometer, right? The alpha term would regulate the efective resistances

Comment: R3 and R5 are the maximum resistance of the potentiometer. And alpha is a wiper position to get "equivalent" resistance. When the wiper is in the upper position alpha=1. In the middle alpha = 0.5 and on the bottom alpha = 0.

Comment: "but all the work that you made is considering R3<<R2, right?" No, it will work always.

Comment: After a few hours I finally understood almost everything, just got stumped at two things: 1) in V_NI, isn't it missing R3 from the denominator in the Vin term? 2)Why were the capacitors not considered for the Vin term? Won't they act as filters of some kind?

Comment: Do you mean this equation ? $$V_{NI} = V_1\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}+ V_{IN}\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} $$

Comment: As for C2 capacitor. I treated C2 as a bypass capacitor (capacitor that shorts any AC signals at V1 point to the ground).

Comment: But wouldn't C2 have a significant impact for the Vin term?

Comment: No, I meant the one with the POT included

Comment: Good job for spotting the mistake. but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all we can exclude \$\text{C}1\$ and \$\text{C}2\$ from our calculation because the're used for filtering etc.

The circuit we are dealing with is given by:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fal43E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In order to solve for \$\text{V}_+\$ we get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}+\text{I}_{\text{R}_3}=\text{I}_{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}=\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_+}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_+-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_3}=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_{\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{V}_+=\frac{\text{R}_2(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4)\text{V}_1+\text{R}_4(\text{R}_3\text{V}_1+\text{R}_1\text{V}_2)}{\text{R}_3(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2)+\text{R}_4(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3)}\tag1
$$

Now, we also know that:

$$\text{V}_-=\frac{\text{R}_5}{\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6}\cdot\text{V}_\text{opamp}\tag2$$

And:

$$\frac{\text{V}_\text{out}}{\text{V}_\text{opamp}}=\frac{\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}{\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{R}_7}=\frac{1}{1+\text{sCR}_7}\tag3$$

Using the fact that in an ideal opamp circuit we have \$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-\$. So we get:

$$\frac{\text{R}_5}{\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6}\cdot\left(1+\text{sCR}_7\right)\text{V}_\text{out}=\frac{\text{R}_2(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4)\text{V}_1+\text{R}_4(\text{R}_3\text{V}_1+\text{R}_1\text{V}_2)}{\text{R}_3(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2)+\text{R}_4(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3)}\tag4$$

---

Using your information we have:

- $$\text{C}=150\cdot10^{-9}\space\text{F}\tag5$$
- $$\text{R}_1=\text{R}_2=\text{R}_5=1000\space\Omega\tag6$$
- $$\text{R}_6=2500\space\Omega\tag7$$
- $$\text{R}_7=12000\space\Omega\tag8$$
- $$\text{V}_2=\frac{5}{\text{s}}\tag9$$
- $$\text{V}_1=\mathcal{L}_t\left[\frac{4}{5}\cdot\sin\left(\omega t\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{\omega}{\text{s}^2+\omega^2}\tag{10}$$

Let's assume that \$\text{R}_3=\text{R}_4=10000\space\Omega\$ and \$\omega=1\space\text{rad/sec}\$. The output voltage is given by:

$$\text{V}_\text{out}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{250\left(25\text{s}^2+48\text{s}+25\right)}{\text{s}\left(5000+9\text{s}\right)\left(\text{s}^2+1\right)}\tag{11}$$

Using inverse Laplace transform we get:

$$\text{v}_\text{out}\left(t\right)=250\left(\frac{1}{200}-\frac{24913681\exp\left(-\frac{5000t}{9}\right)}{5000016200}-\frac{48\left(9\cos\left(t\right)-5000\sin\left(t\right)\right)}{25000081}\right)\tag{12}$$

> I checked my solution using LTspice and my result is indeed correct.